# How to remove Perl6 package installed by Panda

Tags: raku

I was just wondering how one might uninstall a Perl6 package installed by Panda, as it seems to be missing the 'remove' or 'uninstall' command.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As of today, you cannot remove a package with panda; the alternate package manager zef does support this, however.

https://github.com/ugexe/zef

Answer (score 2):

I forget where I found [this](https://gist.github.com/clearairturbulence/462bb072e98b7cc08e3f347de28f6f7f) code for removing something installed via Panda, but it works amazingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;

sub MAIN($short-name, :$ver = True, :$auth = True, :$api = True) {
    my $comp-unit = $*REPO.resolve(CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(:$short-name, :$ver, :$auth, :$api));
    $comp-unit.repo.uninstall($comp-unit.distribution);
}
```

Comment: source of the code is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/niner/b39258032f70c083e57b) by the guy who implemented Rakudo's precompilation system

Comment: yes, just to emphasize it's not me it's that guy. I am not the sharpest cookie in the knife drawer.